# How to extract values from string? (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, regex, nlp

I'am trying to analyze string and decompose it into clear values: `taskValue` and `timeValue`.

```
var str1 = "20 minutes (to do)/(for) some kind of task"
// other possibilities
var str2 = "1 hour 30 minutes for some kind of task"
var str3 = "do some kind of task for 1 hour"
```

How can I apply multiple regexes in one function? Maybe, something like array of regexes

```
["[0-9]{1,} minutes", 
 "[0-9] hour", 
 "[0-9] hour, [0-9]{1,} minutes",
  ...]
```

The values returned from function aren't clean, it remains with `"of ..", "for...", "to..."` etc.

Can you give me advice how to improve it? Maybe it's possible to do some machine learning with MLKit? How to add a couple of regex patterns? Or to check if string contains certain things manually?

```
// check it out
var str = "20 minutes to do some kind of task"
func decompose(_ inputText: String) -> (time: String, taskName: String) {
    
    let pattern = "[0-9]{1,} minutes"
    let regexOptions: NSRegularExpression.Options = [.caseInsensitive]
    let matchingOptions: NSRegularExpression.MatchingOptions = [.reportCompletion]
    let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: inputText.utf8.count)
    
    var time = ""
    var taskName = inputText
    
    let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: regexOptions)
    if let matchIndex = regex.firstMatch(in: inputText, options: matchingOptions, range: range) {
        
        let startIndex = inputText.index(inputText.startIndex, offsetBy: matchIndex.range.lowerBound)
        let endIndex = inputText.index(inputText.startIndex, offsetBy: matchIndex.range.upperBound)
        
        time = String(inputText[startIndex..<endIndex])

        taskName.removeSubrange(startIndex..<endIndex)
           
    } else {
        print("No match.")
    }


    return (time, taskName)
}

print(decompose(str))
```

Overall, I look to learn how to do text analysis on premise that we know the thematics beforehand.

Comment: To do what you're looking to do and not just handle the simplest cases, you probably want to look into "natural language processing". There's an Apple framework for it and quite a few articles/tutorials around that explain how to start using it.

Answer (score 1):

Use capture groups:

```swift
(\d+)\s*minute|(\d+)\s*hour
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/OajRLh/1/). Then check which group matched and use captured values as you need. If the first group matched, you have minutes, else, you have hours in the second group.

**EXPLANATION**

```swift
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  minute                   'minute'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  hour                     'hour'
```